# Password Hashing with JavascriptNodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, password-protection

My experience with password protection is virtually non-existent. I did not take any cryptography classes in college, and my math courses only briefly touched on actual encryption algorithms. Now though, I would like to store user passwords in a database to create a secure method for logging into my app. After reading [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), there are a few things that I have gathered:

- Password hashing should take a significant amount of time, to prevent repeated login attempts and increase security.
- Two or more passwords **could potentially** hash to the same string.

With that in mind, I have tried to implement password hashing on my node server using [jssha](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA). Copying the examples from the readme:

```
var jsSHA = require('jssha');
var sha = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
sha.update("password");
var hash = sha.getHash("HEX");

console.log(hash);
```

I am able to create hashes for the password string, but this module seems to violate two of the above bullet points. Running the script 5 times in a row creates the same string every time, and even using the the optional hashmap in the constructor to add iterations:

```
var sha = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT", '{"numRounds" : 4000000}');
```

the hash is completed in microseconds, regardless of the number of rounds that I supply to the constructor.

I can't really find any documentation for hashing specifically in Javascript/Node. Am I using the module incorrectly, or should I be using something else?

Comment: The third parameter should be an object literal, not a string.

Comment: You'll get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com/.  However, I strongly advise against using SHA-512, as it is largely broken as a secure hash.  The state-of-the-art is scrypt, although HMAC-SHA1 is also considered an acceptable choice.

Comment: Oh really... I shall look into this scrypt.

Comment: Have you taken a look at bcrypt? It doesn't look like jsSHA has any helpers for salts.

Comment: bcrypt is another good alternative to scrypt.

Comment: Are you sure about your first assertion?  Isn't it:  "Passwords *must* hash to the same string on sequential runs of the algorithm."?  Regarding your second assertion, I would suggest that the function can run as quickly as it wants to and yet the authentication method should add an n, n*2, n*4, n*8, ... delay mechanism each failed attempt so that brute force methods require progressively longer.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship, I think you're right. I was playing around with the PHP source code provided in my first link, and I got the impression somehow that the algorithm for verifying a password is different than creating the initial hash. It must just be because the salt and algorithm type are appended to the password hash and stored in the DB and well, and thus must be extracted from the string first. So if I'm using a random salt, I should follow suit and store the salt in the database along with the password string, right?

Comment: @JimmyPruitt Store the salt in the DB only if you can't then put the raw secret into your function and get the hash as a result.  If you can't generate the same hash from your secret then store the salt and use it as a second argument to your hash-generating function.

Answer (score 0):

Node has a built-in module for hash based key stretching: `crypto.pbkdf2`

I use the following function to create hashes:

```
function createHash(password, salt, iterations, hashLength, callback) {
    if(hashLength % 2 !== 0){
        throw new Error("hashLength must be even, because it returns a string of two-character hexadecimal digits.");
    }
    var keyLength = hashLength / 2;
    iterations = iterations || 10000;
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keyLength, function(err, bytes){
        var hash = Buffer(bytes, 'binary').toString('hex');
        callback(err, hash);
    });
}
```

...where `password` is the literal text to convert to a hash, `salt` is a random string to be stored along with the password, `iterations` is the number of times to repeat the key stretching algorithm, `keyLength` is how long the hexadecimal hash string should end up being, and `callback` returns the hash to the calling code.

I store the iterations and the key length in the same database row with the hash and salt rather than in configuration, so I have the option of hardening the encryption as the user updates his or her password.

The crypto module also includes a salt creation method `crypto.randomBytes`, which I use like so:

```
function createSalt(saltLength, callback){
    if(saltLength % 2 !== 0){
        throw new Error("saltLength must be even, because it returns a string of two-character hexadecimal digits.");
    }
    var byteLength = saltLength / 2;
    crypto.randomBytes(byteLength, function(err, bytes){
        var salt = Buffer(bytes, 'binary').toString('hex');
        callback(err, salt);
    });
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not a cryptographer either. :)

Comment: Why did you choose PBKDF2 over Scrypt, Bcrypt, and HMAC-SHA1 like others are suggesting?

Comment: Because it's Node's default implementation. What drew me to it was not its strength, but the fact that I assume, as Node's built-in library, that it's going to be well maintained and widely tested. Is it the strongest available algorithm? Probably not, but other schemes appear to have other drawbacks (such as high memory usage for the arguably more secure scrypt) and it seems secure enough for my purposes. FWIW, it's mentioned alongside bcrypt in that Crackstation article you posted as a "standard algorithm."